# Getting specific value from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a single value of a logged user but I always end up with array.

```
   $sss = $db->prepare('SELECT Level FROM registrace where ID = :ID ');
   $sss->bindParam(':ID', $_SESSION['ID']);
   $sss->execute();
   $result = $sss->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   if($result > 1) {
    echo '<a href="AdminPanel.php" class="admin"> Add Post </a>'; 
   } 
   echo $result ;
```

$result always ends up beeing array, how to get the Number in "Level" from database?

Comment: @chris85 Oh, right. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would access the value with:

```
$result['Level']
```

Per the manual; http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php.

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: Return next row as an array indexed by column name

Answer (score 0):

try to change as below,you are doing wrong comparison in the if statement.

```
if($result > 1) {
```

to

```
if($result['Level'] > 1) {
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.